# Top bar iOS app with RubyMotion?

Tags: ios, ruby, rubymotion

I'm very new to RubyMotion and iOS development and I wanna put a top bar in my app, like [this one from groupme](http://g.virbcdn.com/_f/cdn_images/resize_640x640/8b/PageImage-489404-3066350-IMG_5477.PNG) and place an icon in the middle of it.

How do I do that? What is the library? How do I attach it to the view?

There is the code in my `app_delegate.rb`, currently:

```
class AppDelegate
  def application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
    @window = UIWindow.alloc.initWithFrame(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds)

    tabbar = UITabBarController.alloc.init
    tabbar.viewControllers = [
        ProductMapController.alloc.init,
        SearchController.alloc.init,
        NewProductController.alloc.init,
        FeedController.alloc.init,
        UserDetailsController.alloc.init
    ]
    tabbar.selectedIndex = 0
    @window.rootViewController = UINavigationController.alloc.initWithRootViewController(tabbar)
    @window.rootViewController.wantsFullScreenLayout = true
    @window.makeKeyAndVisible

    true
  end
end
```

Thank you, I appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: There's no library, you build it yourself.  The background image of the bar would be a UIImageView.  Then create a UIButton and add it as a subview.  Voila, done. :)

Comment: This sounds easy when you say but I'm so newbie, how would you do that in the code above, can you tell me?

Comment: The code you've posted above is familiar to me in content but not syntax; I program iOS in Objective-C, not ruby. But I'm sure there is documentation out there for how to place images and buttons on the screen in ruby, yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for this:

In my `app_delegate.rb` I have:

```
items_controller = ProductsController.alloc.initWithNibName(nil, bundle: nil)
@window.rootViewController = UINavigationController.alloc.initWithRootViewController(items_controller)
```

then in my `items_controller.rb` I have:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView.alloc.initWithImage(UIImage.imageNamed('logo.png'))
```

I think this is totally fine because i'm not really polluting my `app_delegate.rb` anymore :)

If you have a better solution, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea of what you want:

```
class AppDelegate
  def application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
    @window = UIWindow.alloc.initWithFrame UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds
    @window.makeKeyAndVisible

    #creates a bar with a width of 320, a height of 100, and colors it blue
    bar = UIView.alloc.initWithFrame [[0, 0], [320, 100]]  
    bar.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor 

    #creates an imageView with the icon, change the coordinates to center your icon
    icon= UIImageView.alloc.initWithFrame([[100,0], [100,100]]) 
    icon.image = UIImage.imageNamed('youricon.jpeg')

    #adds the bar and icon to the window
    @window.addSubview bar
    @window.addSubview icon

    true
  end
end
```

You don't want this sort of code in your app delegate but I added it here to give you a simple example.